# How to use foreach for IQueryable objects?

Tags: linq, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

I am using MVC4 and MongoDB.I want to make a table according to the elements of a IQueryable object . My object is this :

```
 IQueryable<EventReport> Events = ViewBag.EventsByDevice_Type;
```

This "var result" is sent from the controller in ViewBag:

```
var result = (from dn in ObjectMongoCollection.AsQueryable<DataLog>()
                      where (dn.LogStatus == Enums.LogStatus.Alarm)
                        &&  (deviceIdList.Contains(dn.DeviceId))
                        && (dn.ReadingDateUTC >= startDateUTC && dn.CreateDate <= endDateUTC)
                        && (dn.DeviceId == deviceId || deviceId == "")
                        && (dn.LogType == LogType || logType == "" || logType == null)
                     group dn by new { device = dn.DeviceId, type = dn.LogType } into report
                     select new EventReport 
                     {
                        DeviceId = report.Key.device,
                        LogType = report.Key.type,
                        EventCount=""+report.Count()    
                     });
```

An IQueyable object is sent from the controller.There is no problem about controller.However I can not use this IQueryable in foreach loop :

```
foreach (var item in Events)
{
 .
 .
 .
}
```

It does not give compile error but when I try to run it following error occurs on the foreach line :

"System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Object' and 'System.String'."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add a `result.ToList()` to force immediate query evaluation and check which LINQ line throws that exception.

Comment: You mean do  " var result= ............ }).ToList();" right? I tried this but it gives the same error. How can I learn which LINQ line throws the exception? Can you tell me pls?